# Error: No Match for operator[]

Tags: c++, vector, openframeworks

I'm working on an openFrameworks project, and I'm using a `vector` to store 3d mesh index locations. However, when attempting to access the data, I'm getting:

> ```
> error: no match for 'operator []' in ((icoSphere*)this)->icoSphere::subIndicies[i]
> ```

The data type is `ofIndexType`.

Here are some snippets

icoSphere.h file:

```
// vector created        
std::vector<ofIndexType> subIndicies;
```

icoSphere.cpp file:

```
// items added to vector
ofIndexType indA = mesh.getIndex(0);
ofIndexType indB = mesh.getIndex(1);
ofIndexType indC = mesh.getIndex(2);

subIndicies.push_back(indA);
subIndicies.push_back(indB);
subIndicies.push_back(indC);

// iterate through vector
for (std::vector<ofIndexType>::iterator i = subIndicies.begin(); i !=subIndicies.end(); i++)
{
    subMesh.addIndex(subIndicies[i]); // here is where the error occurs
}
```

Both the vector and the iterator are `ofIndexType` (an openFrameworks data type, which is essentially an unsigned integer). Can't sort out why it's saying `[]` isn't an operator.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`std::vector::operator[]()` expects an **integer index** (a `size_t`) referring to a vector item:

```
0 --> 1st item
1 --> 2nd item
2 --> 3rd item
....
```

But in your code you passed an **iterator** (which is not an integer index) as parameter to `std::vector::operator[]()`, which is invalid:

> ```
> // *** 'i' is an iterator, not an integer index here ***
> //
> for (vector<ofIndexType>::iterator i = subIndices.begin(); i != subIndices.end(); i++)
> {
>     subMesh.addIndex(subIndices[i]); // here is where the error occurs
> }
> ```

Either use *iterators* to access vector items, or use *integer indices*.
In C++11+, it's also possible to use *range-based `for` loops*.

```
// Integer index
for (size_t i = 0; i < subIndices.size(); ++i)
{
    subMesh.addIndex(subIndices[i]);
}

// Iterator
for (auto it = subIndices.begin(); it != subIndices.end(); ++it)
{
    subMesh.addIndex(*it);
}

// Modern C++11+ range for
for (const auto & elem : subIndices)
{
    subMesh.addIndex(elem);
}
```

---

**PS**
Note that, when you increment an *iterator*, it's better to use pre-increment `++it` instead of post-increment `it++` (`it++` is a "premature pessimization").

Answer (score 5):

i is an iterator, just do

```
subMesh.addIndex(*i);
```